# Mapping variable names to value in predefined types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined two types as shown below with Vname representing a variable name as a string and Val representing an integer value:

```
type Vname = String
type Val = Int
type State = ...
```

with the type State still to be defined (I am also not sure if I have done Vname and Val correctly either). State has to be a mapping between Vname and Val and I assume it would be along the lines of:

```
type State = Vname->Val
```

but I am really not sure. Any clarification on this would be helpful.

it is for an implementation of a low-level machine with commands to operate a stack, with `Vname` being the variable name of the number you are putting onto the stack and `Val` being the value. The types are there for custom ghci input names.

Thank you.

Comment: This is impossible to answer as it currently stands. How are we supposed to know what any of these types is for?

Comment: @leftaroundabout it is for an implementation of a low-level machine with commands to operate a stack, with Vname being the variable name of the number you are putting onto the stack and Val being the value. The types are there for custom ghci input names. I hope this is helpful, I apologise if not, I have not been taught Haskell too effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise, you've defined two type *aliases*, not two types.

`State` could be a function:

```
type State = Vname -> Maybe Val

foo :: State
foo "x" = Just 3
foo "y" = Just 5
-- etc
foo _ = Nothing
```

or it could be a list of name/value pairs.

```
type State' = [(Vname, Val)]

foo' :: State'
foo' = [("x", 3), ("y", 5)]
```

Note that `foo` and `\x -> lookup x foo'` (or `flip lookup foo'`) are basically the same function.

Which you choose depends mostly on how you plan to use a value of type `State`. Sometimes the function will be more convenient, other times the list of pairs. I might lean toward the list, as it's easier to create a functional form (using `lookup`, as shown above) from a list than it is to create a list from a function (as that requires a list of values to apply the function to).